# Had $\sf Con(ZFC)$ been explicitly written in first order language?

Tags: logic, set-theory, first-order-logic

One always hear of $\sf Con(ZFC)$ and what is meant by that is an arithmetical sentence that is equivalent to $\sf ZFC \text { is consistent }$ that is written in the language of first order $\sf ZFC$. However, I've never seen an actual first order sentence expressing this? Had this statement been explicitly written in the first order language of set theory before? and where can I find examples of such write-ups

Comment: If you read a textbook on Godel’s incompleteness theorems (say Smullyan’s) you will generally find a clear construction of such a statement for Con(PA) in the language of arithmetic. (Although it will be constructed piece by piece using lots of definitional extensions, so you’ll never see the whole thing written out in full in $L_A$.) I’m not sure of a place where this is done for con(ZFC) in the language of set theory, but it is actually easier. A lot of effort is spent finding clever ways to express things in arithmetic whereas set theory more expressive so requires less cleverness.

Comment: Actually, Con(ZFC) is in the language of arithmetic. In the language of set theory it would just be "there is a set which is a model of ZFC"...

Comment: @Asaf well there is a proof theoretical and a model theoretical statement, both of which are expressible in set theory (and equivalent over something much weaker than ZF ).

Comment: @AsafKaragila "there is set which is a model of ZFC" is not by itself in the language of ZFC, but there is an equivalent formula in the language of set theory, but what is that equivalent formula? for example How long it is? I need to see the formula itself. That's what I'm asking for.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen, from this I get the impression that it is a very long formula! right?

Comment: Of course it is. The whole notion of a model is formalized in ZFC.

Comment: @Zuhair you need to formalize formulas, structures and satisfaction of sentences in structures in set theory (I.e. the traditional basic definitions of model theory.) Formulas are probably best handled by using nested ordered pairs to build the syntax tree, then satisfaction can be defined inductively by parsing that. Also you need to figure out how to recognize ZFC axioms. It probably takes a few pages to lay it out at a very fine level of detail.

Comment: Can you write it for me.

Comment: You people are speaking about the capability of being done in the language of set theory, I know that this can be done! That's not my question. My question is that I want to see this formula. I want to see the first order formula that says "is a model of" for example.

Comment: Well, I gave a (granted not very detailed) description of how to do it.

Comment: At the end of the day, how long are those formulas you are speaking about, are they very long formulas.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen. Imagine having to write the def'n of Godel's constructible class $L$ using only $\in$ and $=$.